# optimizing nested if statements with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently building an API for another piece of software; we are using a token id with transnational replacement for user authorization maintenance. We are trying to determine the faster(and less resource intensive) mode to complete the task of a nested if statement (whether we should use php to operate the if statement or allow the mysql engine to complete the task.

It can be noted the same server is operating MySQL and PHP so there is not the benefit of load diversion by splitting the argument between two servers.

our options as we see it is the following:

PHP Driven if statement

```
            $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT uid
            ,ukey
            FROM token 
            WHERE ukey = :ukey AND uid = :uid AND timeexp >= now()");
            $sql->execute(array('ukey' => $curtoken, 'uid' => $uid));
            $result = $sql->fetchAll();

            if ( count($result) ) {
                //New MySQL Statement to run our action
            }
```

or using mysql if/where statements

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
SELECT value_for_column1, value_for_column2, ...
FROM wherever
WHERE ((SELECT count(*) FROM `Token` WHERE ukey = :ukey AND uid = :uid AND timeexp >= now()) =1)
```

Comment: Do you have a composite index on ukey and uid? What're the max # of records for a given ukey+uid combination? Instead of `select uid, ukey`, just ask for `select count(*)`. Then, use `$result = $sql->fetchColumn();`. Now, your `if` statement can do numeric comparison like so: `if ($result > 0) {...}`.

Comment: at this moment there is no composite index as the table is only 4 columns wide including the Auto_incremented primary key. There is not a possibility of more than one record every being retrieved by this query as old key rows are purged once expired (or used once)

Comment: Your insert's `where ...` can be rewritten as `where exists (select 1 from token where...)`

Comment: that would be acceptable and likely more appropriate; I was trying to type the concept quickly after doing some research

Comment: Gotcha. How many records does `token` have? A few hundreds, thousands, millions? If you have a few thousands, you will benefit from uid+ukey composite index. Few hundreds - meh. More than 10K, that index will definitely help. You're using that combination to search in both your select and insert...select.

Comment: it is on a 5 minute purge for keys older than 1 minute so it is not likely to have more than 50-100

Comment: Cool, scan of 50-100 rows will be fast. So, only two takeaways come to mind - `where exists` and `select count(*)` with `fetchColumn()`

Comment: Do you want me to add that as an answer or would you like to test it out first and then add your own answer with findings? It's a good question you asked!

Comment: I am getting better response time with your solutions; add as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple places where optimization can be done.

**Indexes**

Since `select ukey, uid...where ukey = :ukey AND uid = :uid...` uses ukey,uid pair, there may be value in putting a composite index on ukey+uid.

INSERT has a subquery that uses those 2 columns as well and could benefit from the index. However, if there are 50-100 rows, I doubt index will have significant influence. Table scan may be equally quick. If the table gets to be a few thousand records, consider the composite index.

**Ask for count rather than fields**

If you were to switch from `select ukey, uid...` to `select count(*)`, the data returned from the database will be a single number. Fewer bits will go between application and database and throughput will improve. I don't know whether the improvement will be noticeable unless it is running at scale.

There might be a PHP-related benefit. Instead of `$result = $sql->fetchAll()`, you could use `$count = $sql->fetchColumn()` to get the count directly in a variable. PHP can then do comparisons quicker with `if ($count > 0) ...`

**Where exists**

```
WHERE (
   SELECT count(*)
   FROM `Token`
   WHERE ukey = :ukey AND uid = :uid AND timeexp >= now() = 1
)
```

could be replaced with something like this:

```
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM `Token`
   WHERE ukey = :ukey AND uid = :uid AND timeexp >= now())
)
```

That way, a `count(*)` and comparison therefore to 1 is not needed.

You're already doing a nice job of purging information routinely to keep a small, clean set of data. That'll help with querying and scaling.